# Passing an array in a single argument using jQuery deffered.resolveWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a [jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which I an resolving like so:

```
deferredAction.resolve(returnArray);
```

and this is calling a callback like:

```
function someCallback(myArray) {
...
}
```

This works fine, the callback function receives the array.  However I need to set the context of the callback function, so I used [deferred.resolveWith](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/) like so:

```
deferredAction.resolveWith(someContext, returnArray);
```

The context is now being set correctly. However, it now seems as if the returnArray is being split up.  **My callback only receives the first item of the array.**

**Why is this happening, and how can I work around it?**

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/) states that you should pass the arguments in a single array. In your case:

`deferredAction.resolveWith(someContext, [returnArray]);`

Comment: I did read the documentation (Do you think I would link to it without doing so?) - obvously I missed this. No need to be obtuse.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Actually, I didn't notice that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by putting square brackets around the return parameter:

```
deferredAction.resolveWith(someContext, [returnArray]);
```

Comment: angle brackets are chevrons `⟨ ⟩` you have your terms mixed up.